# I don't want to waste a line in Beamer

Tags: beamer, environments, presentations

I am using the document class `Beamer`. When I type

```
\begin{definition}
 
This is a definition. 

\end{definition}
```

it returns something like

> Definition
>
> This is a definition.

But this waste an entire line. I would like something like

> Definition. This is a definition.

Is there an easy way of doing this? I have some experience with LaTeX, but I'm completely new to Beamer document class...

Comment: In a presentation lines are not "wasted". If you try and cram as much on the slide as you can you will produce a difficult to read slide. Space your information out more!

Answer (score 10):

The "wasted" line is in reality the title of a block, with a suitable colour theme your definition looks like

[image]

Now if you want to remove the title, maybe the following quick hack could be a solution (There might be some features of definitions that won't work any more).

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Warsaw}

\renewenvironment{definition}{\begin{block}{}\translate{Definition}.}{\end{block}}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
    bla

    \begin{definition}
        This is a definition.
    \end{definition}
\end{frame} 

\end{document}
```

[image]